Is there a way to use pointers of constant strings as ids?
Is there a way to guarantee that a compiler uses the same
pointer for same value string constants?
void *gettok() {
  ...
  return "if";
}
...
tok = gettok();
...
if (tok == "if") {...}

without going through some map and without overloading "=="?
I just want to use the constant string pointer as an id.

No because: "...Whether all string literals are stored in nonoverlapping objects and whether successive evaluations of a string literal yield the same or a different object is unspecified.---" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

There is no guarantee, and no way to force there to be a guarantee, that two distinct string literals with the same content  (e.g.  "if" in some scope, "if" in another scope) will have the same address.   So it is quite feasible that, in your partial example, tok == "if" will test false.   In C++, it is possible to change gettok() so its return type is std::string, and tok == "if" will test true, but the mechanics of this is quite different from pointer comparison.   In C, offhand, I cannot think of a simple alternative.

A C implementation may specify that it consolidates identical string literals, but I do not see a statement in the GCC (for example) documentation that says it does this. It also requires linker support, since the compiler cannot unify identical string literals in two separate translation units. (There is allusion to GCC doing that here, but it does not cite a source.)

But is there maybe some trick? You can use a constexp hash function to generate case values from const strings for switch statements... is there maybe something similar for this usecase?

Name each string by defining it with const char MyName[] = "MyString";, then use their names in the source code.

@Peter: Re “… no way to force there to be a guarantee”: Of course there is a way to guarantee this: Compile the compiler and linker yourself with source code that coalesces identical string literals.

Duplicate of ensure-that-char-pointers-always-point-to-the-same-string-literal/ for C++

@EricPostpischil   Yeah, of course.   Then come to rely on the feature.  Then, whenever you port your program to a new system, you either need to port your compiler and linker, or rewrite a compiler and linker that target the new platform to do the same thing.    The sort of maintenance that every programmer dreams of.

You can, but you cannot expect the compiler (or the language implementation) to ensure that the same string literal will be unique in a program.  This situation gets worse when you include dynamically constructed strings in the problem.
A simple solution for that is to intern the strings.  This is, create a module  that warrants that the strings you use in your application (statically or dynamically created) are unique.  A simple hash table, a red/blue tree, or an avl tree will give you with enough support for all strings.
Instead of comparing the pointers as they are received, you proceed to intern them (you just use a function that returns the interned version of the string --intern(const char *s) should be an idempotent function) and compare the interned versions.  Depending on your implementation it is easy to achieve, that your references to the same strings are always equal.
Beware that you can run out of resources if you expose the creation of new strings to a bad behaved user.
I will not go in the details on how to construct such implementation, but basically the use case is:
void *gettok() {
  ...
  return intern("if");
}
...
tok = gettok();
...
if (tok == intern("if")) {...}


This I recognize from ruby.

A technique that I used in the 1980s in C:
Define a list of strings in a separate file - say strlist.h.  Do not add guards to this file.
STR(if)
STR(then)
STR(else)
STR(elseif)

In a separate C (strlist.c) file, declare the strings
#ifndef STR_ENUM_H
#define STR_ENUM_H
#define STR(x) #x
const char* str[] = {
    #include "strlist.h"
    "" };
#undef STR
#endif

In a separate file header file (strdef.h), declare the enums
#define STR(x) str_##x,
enum strenum = {
   #include "strlist.h"
    str_max };
#undef STR
extern const char* str[];

The code then becomes
#include "strdef.h"
...
void *gettok() {
  ...
  return str[str_if];

...
tok = gettok();
...
if (tok == str[str_if]) {...}

Maintenance is super easy - whenever a new string is needed, just add it to strlist.h and rebuild.  You can even rearrange the strings, say in alphabetical order: there is no need to always add them at the end.  The enums will change automatically.

This technique is a variant of “X Macros”.

I didn't know about X macros https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_macro  .  There was no internet in those days so all these were home-brew techniques.with no names.

@cup, "The code then becomes ..." deserves a #include "TBD" to illustrate which one of the prior files is to be included.

@cup STR(some string with spaces) seems to be a problem.

Op didn't say whether or not there were spaces.  Agreed - it will not work on a string with spaces.

I would just use an object with static storage duration in the comparisons, for example
const char *tok_if = "if";

const char *gettok(void) {
    return tok_if;
}

int main(void) {
    if (gettok() == tok_if)
        puts("do stuff");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

If you want to also store enum constants with the strings, you can make it more manageable with X-macros, they're nice to use for defining tables.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "tok.h"

int main(void) {
    Tok tok_if = TOK_IF;
    Tok tok_else = TOK_ELSE;
    printf("%s %s\n", tokstr(tok_if), tokstr(tok_else)); // "if else"
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// tok.h
#ifndef TOK_H
#define TOK_H

#define TOK_TABLE(X) \
    X(TOK_IF, "if"), \
    X(TOK_ELSE, "else")

#define X(tok, str) tok
typedef enum {
    TOK_TABLE(X),
    TOK_COUNT
} Tok;
#undef X

const char *tokstr(Tok tok);

#endif

// tok.c
#include "tok.h"

#define X(tok, str) str
static const char *strs[TOK_COUNT] = {
    TOK_TABLE(X),
};
#undef X

const char *tokstr(Tok tok) {
    return strs[tok];
}

If you want to be able to add and remove these tokens at runtime, you could use a simple hash table.
This one is a simplified version from the K&R C book without any values for the keys.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "hash.h"

int main(void) {
    HashNode **tbl = calloc(HASH_BUCKETS, sizeof(*tbl));
    hash_add(tbl, "if");
    printf("%s\n", hash_lookup(tbl, "if") ? "found": "not found"); // "found"
    printf("%s\n", hash_lookup(tbl, "else") ? "found": "not found"); // "not found"
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// hash.h
#ifndef HASH_H
#define HASH_H

#define HASH_BUCKETS 101

typedef struct HashNode {
    struct HashNode *next;
    char *name;
} HashNode;

unsigned int hash(char *s);
HashNode *hash_lookup(HashNode **tbl, char *s);
void hash_add(HashNode **tbl, char *s);

#endif

// hash.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "hash.h"

unsigned int hash(char *s) {
    unsigned int val = 0;
    for (; *s; s++) val = *s + 31 * val;
    return val % HASH_BUCKETS;
}

HashNode *hash_lookup(HashNode **tbl, char *s) {
    for (HashNode *n = tbl[hash(s)]; n; n = n->next)
        if (n->name && !strcmp(n->name, s)) return n;
    return NULL;
}

void hash_add(HashNode **tbl, char *s) {
    if (hash_lookup(tbl, s))
        return;
    else {
        unsigned int val = hash(s);
        HashNode *n = calloc(1, sizeof(*n));
        n->name = strdup(s);
        n->next = tbl[val];
        tbl[val] = n;
    }
}


If instead of pointers a unique "id" is also enough. I once made this constexpr map that allows you to setup an association between an id and a string_view.
#include <string_view>
#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace ce
{
    namespace map_details
    {
        struct index_range_t
        {
            constexpr index_range_t() = default;
            constexpr ~index_range_t() = default;

            constexpr index_range_t(const size_t new_from, const size_t new_to) :
                from{ new_from },
                to{ new_to },
                middle{ (from + to) / 2 }
            {
            }

            constexpr index_range_t left()
            {
                size_t new_to = (middle > to) ? middle - 1 : middle;
                return index_range_t(from, new_to);
            }

            constexpr index_range_t right()
            {
                size_t new_from = (from < middle) ? middle : middle + 1;
                return index_range_t(new_from, to);
            }

            size_t from;
            size_t to;
            size_t middle;
        };

        template<typename key_t, typename value_t>
        struct map_entry_t
        {
            constexpr map_entry_t() = default;
            ~map_entry_t() = default;

            map_entry_t(const map_entry_t&) = default;
            map_entry_t& operator=(const map_entry_t&) = default;

            map_entry_t(map_entry_t&&) = default;
            map_entry_t& operator=(map_entry_t&&) = default;

            constexpr map_entry_t(key_t&& k, value_t&& v) :
                key{ k },
                value{ v }
            {
            }

            key_t key{};
            value_t value{};
        };

        template<typename key_t, typename value_t, std::size_t size_v>
        class map
        {
        public:
            constexpr map() = default;
            constexpr ~map() = default;

            explicit constexpr map(const map_entry_t<key_t, value_t>(&entries)[size_v])
            {
                static_assert(size_v > 0ul);

                for (auto& entry : entries)
                {
                    insert(entry);
                }
            }

            constexpr const auto& operator[](const key_t& key) const
            {
                index_range_t index_range{ 0, size_v - 1ul };
                do
                {
                    if (m_entries[index_range.middle].key == key)
                    {
                        return m_entries[index_range.middle].value;
                    }

                    index_range = (key < m_entries[index_range.middle].key) ? index_range.left() : index_range.right();

                } while (index_range.from != index_range.to);

                throw std::runtime_error("value for key not found");
            }

        private:
            constexpr void insert(const map_entry_t<key_t, value_t>& entry)
            {
                std::size_t insert_pos{ 0ul };
                while ((insert_pos < m_size) && (entry.key > m_entries[insert_pos].key)) insert_pos++;

                if (m_entries[insert_pos].key == entry.key) throw std::invalid_argument("Duplicate key found");

                // shift entries to the back
                for (std::size_t n = m_size; n > insert_pos; --n)
                {
                    m_entries[n] = m_entries[n - 1];
                }

                //todo avoid duplicate keys
                m_entries[insert_pos] = entry;
                m_size++;
            }

            std::size_t m_size{ 0ul };
            std::array<map_entry_t<key_t, value_t>, size_v> m_entries{};
        };
    } // namespace map_details

    template<typename key_t, typename value_t, std::size_t size_v>
    static constexpr auto make_map(const map_details::map_entry_t<key_t, value_t>(&entries)[size_v])
    {
        map_details::map<key_t, value_t, size_v> map{ entries };
        return map;
    }

} // namespace ce


int main()
{
    using namespace std::string_view_literals;

    static constexpr auto ce_map = ce::make_map<int, std::string_view>({
        {1,"one"sv},
        {4,"four"sv},
        {3,"three"sv},
        {5,"five"sv},
        {2,"two"sv}
        });

    static_assert(ce_map[1] == "one"sv);
    static_assert(ce_map[3] == "three"sv);

    return 0;
}

Note: you could move the map to a header file and declare it as inline constexpr


without going through some map and without overloading "=="

I would do just:
const char *const IF = "if";
const char *const ELSE = "else";

void *gettok() {
  ...
  return IF;
}
...
tok = gettok();
...
if (tok == IF) {...}

